# Error when checking for username and password

Tags: java, sql

Im currently attempting to make a login system in Java and SQL and am currently getting an error.

```
PreparedStatement s1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dbo.Logins WHERE Username=? AND Password=?");
s1.setString(1,loginUsername);
s1.setString(2, loginPassword.toString());
ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery();

if(rs.next()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Found");
}
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
}
```

When I run that snippet of code it always displays the else part of the if/else and im not sure why. Thank in advance.

Edit: Yes the DB is populated with users.
Edit2: I changed the function to require two string args.

Comment: it's simply mean no match found , you sure you have saved data in DB

Comment: I am able to print the table to console so it is definitely saved.

Comment: Why do you use `loginUsername` directly but `loginPassword.toString()` and not `loginPassword` directly?

Comment: I use `loginPassword.toString()` because the password is input into a password field and is saved as `char[]`

Answer (score 0):

You must try to use `while(rs.next())` instead of `if(rs.next())`.

If that does not work, does your DB (which you have mentioned is populated), contain those particular values of username and password that you are searching for ? If not, that may be the problem.

If that too does not work, you may have closed some objects (eg. s1.close() or con.close() ) where you shouldn't. For further help on that you will need to provide a more detailed flow of what you have done in the whole code.

Comment: added the while(rs.next()) around the if statement and now neither pop up comes up. Did I place it in the wrong spot or is this a different error

Comment: try using while instead of the if ()

Comment: tried the while loop, got nothing and the DB contains the login im using.

Comment: Then post the whole code please. You may have closed some objects where you shouldn't I assume.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch number of rows available in your table for given query and if it is great than 0 it will execute User Found statement.

```
PreparedStatement s1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dbo.Logins WHERE Username=? AND Password=?");
s1.setString(1,loginUsername);
s1.setString(2, loginPassword.toString());
ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery();

int rowCount = rs.last() ? rs.getRow() : 0; //Number of rows available in table for query

if(rowCount>0)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Found");
}
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed here, and why? The answer isn't terribly useful without some accompanying descriptions.

Comment: @nbrooks updated my answer. rs.next() always returns on "select ...". The question is whether the count is greater than zero. So, for that I used rowCount.

Comment: got this com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void Login(String user, String pass) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            String userName = "<USERNAME>";
            String password = "<PASSWORD>";
            String url = "<URL>";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            PreparedStatement s1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dbo.Logins WHERE Username=? AND Password=?");
            s1.setString(1,user);
            s1.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery();           

            //int rowCount = rs.last() ? rs.getRow() : 0; //Number of rows
            System.out.println("Name: " + user + "\nPass: " + pass);

            if(rs.next())
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Found");

            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
            }
            con.close();
```